# Remove Breaks from start and end of the paragraph using Regular expression

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have my html snippet like below

---

```
<B>Summary:</B><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<P><BR><SPAN style="WIDOWS: 2; TEXT-TRANSFORM: none; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(255,255,255); TEXT-INDENT: 0px; LETTER-SPACING: normal; DISPLAY: inline !important; FONT: 13px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; WHITE-SPACE: normal; ORPHANS: 2; FLOAT: none; COLOR: rgb(0,0,0); WORD-SPACING: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px">Web developer can also use Regular Expression in JavaScript. Now I describe some simple examples of using Regular Expression in JavaScript.</SPAN></P><BR>
<P><BR><A href="http://www.yahoo.com">www.yahoo.com</A></P><BR>
<P><BR><A href="http://www.orkut.com">www.orkut.com</A></P><BR><BR>
```

---

> `I want to remove all the <BR> tags between </B> and <P> tags(</B><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
>       <P>)`

. how can I do that using a javascript regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If there's exactly 5:

```
var str = "<B>...";
str = str.replace(/(<BR>){5}/, '');
```

Comment: How are you selecting the string?

Comment: the above html is the output of the CKEditor.So I am implementing the  "CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().replace(/(<BR>){5}/, '');"

Comment: Is it outputting the same, unchanged code, or is it just outputting nothing?

Comment: it's outputting the unchanged code.There is no difference when i output the data with CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData() and CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().replace(/(<BR>){5}/, '');

Comment: It's working when I assign the output to a string. You could try `replace(/(<BR>){5}/g, '');`.